# Verification of the Firebase Domains

Tags: firebase, google-fit, google-cloud-console

I'm seeing the 'Pending developer action' warning when I go to the OAuth consent screen of my project.

Please see the details of the warning that I'm seeing below.

> *Comply with domain verification requirements Ensure that your application's domains have completed the Search Console verification
> process.*

There are 3 domains listed under the 'Authorised domains' section. The first one and the second one are the domains auto-generated by Firebase and I have already verified the third one.

I've read that if I get in touch with the verification team and explain the situation, they understand it and verify the app but can't get a response from them.

Is there anyone faced with a similar situation?